# U 16.04 Terminal got weird behavior: TAB interrupts input instead of suggestion

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I didn't experienced this before! I start typing

```
service netw
```

I meant network-manager
Instead Terminal breaks my input by output

```
$ service netwThe program 'awk' can be found in the following packages:
* gawk
* mawk
* original-awk
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
ork
```

What's wrong?

```
$ update-alternatives --display awk
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/bin/gawk (part of link group awk) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
awk - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/mawk
  link currently points to /usr/bin/gawk
  link awk is /usr/bin/awk
  slave awk.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/awk.1.gz
  slave nawk is /usr/bin/nawk
  slave nawk.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/nawk.1.gz
/usr/bin/mawk - priority 5
  slave awk.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/mawk.1.gz
  slave nawk: /usr/bin/mawk
  slave nawk.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/mawk.1.gz

$ type -a awk mawk gawk
bash: type: awk: not found
mawk is /usr/bin/mawk

bash: type: gawk: not found
```

Comment: Add the output of `update-alternatives --display awk` and `type -a awk mawk gawk` please

Comment: I tried install **awk**, **gawk** and **original-awk** and it's working now. I don't understand what cause this. I didn't install \ uninstall anything recently.

Comment: `bash-completion` (the package responsible for figuring out the possible completions) tried to use `awk` internally.